# "if" doesn`t want to register same strings from two arrays

Tags: arrays, if-statement

Why is the line " System.out.println(morse[0]);" not being executed

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] english = {"a", "b"};

    String[] morse = { "...."};
    String[] morseCodeMas = ".... ".split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i != english.length - 1; i++) {
            //if (morseCodeMas[ki]==morse[i]){
            if (morseCodeMas[0]=="...."){
                System.out.println(morse[0]);
            }
        }
    }
```

But if change morseCodeMas incoming string to "...." it will work

Comment: Don't compare strings with '==', use .equals().  Also, are the strings are different?

Comment: Comparing strings with `==` asks whether both variables are referring to the same string (same location in memory), which is usually not what you want. The reason it worked when you changed `morseCodeMas` to "...." is because the compiler saw that you have the same string twice in the code and optimised it by storing just one copy; both variables referred to that one copy, so they compare as `==`. That's not something you can rely on; another compiler (or the same compiler with different options) might skip that optimisation and store the two copies separately.

Answer (score -1):

You should use equals to compare

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] english = {"a", "b"};

    String[] morse = { "...."};
    String[] morseCodeMas = ".... ".split(" ");;
    

        for (int i = 0; i != english.length - 1; i++) {
            if (morseCodeMas[0].equals("....")){
                System.out.println(morse[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They're using split, so the space should be removed.